# Edit user profil properties with jquery sharepoint hosted app

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, office365

I created a sharepoint hosted app for Office 365, I want to update the user profile properties. I used this code:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);
peopleManager.setSingleValueProfileProperty(targetUser, "Activite", $("#txt_Activite").val());
context.executeQueryAsync(function () {
   //editeProfil();
   window.parent.location = hostweburl + "/Pages/MONPROFIL.aspx?&UserTarget=" + targetUser;
       }, onFail);

function onFail(data, args)
{
    console.log(args.get_message());
}
```

When I want to edit my profile property it's ok, but with other user profile's I have this error:

```
Access denied
```

I used an admin account.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the fact that the context object is from the normal site collection (current). If you create a context for the -admin site, then, it will work.

If for example, your tenant name is test, your context should be from https://test-admin.sharepoint.com and i believe it will work.

I tested this on the CSOM, but, I ebelive it should work for the JSOM as well.

Regards,
Jag